# Bug: Vote down after voting up

Tags: support, down-votes

If I vote up a question or answer and later decide to vote it down (if I changed my mind or it was a mistake), it votes it down by 2 points.

This means that after the upvote the votes are 1, after the downvote the votes are -1. Should the votes not be 0 after doing this?

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Unless I've misunderstood what you're saying, this is normal.

What is happening is:

1. The post starts on 0.
2. You upvote it (0 → 1).
3. You then *remove your upvote* (1 → 0) and *downvote* (0 → -1) in one action by swapping your upvote for a downvote.
4. Final score is no upvotes and one downvote, so a total of -1.

If you just want to *remove* a vote, then you can just press the highlighted arrow - this will remove the vote as though it never happened (so would be just the 1 → 0 action from the sequence above).

Comment: That's right. I did not realize to vote down a question because you upvoted my mistake, you have to vote him up again. A little bit counter intuitive but it is there. May be a helpful message if someone does it would be helpful.

Comment: @Dave It's similar to a [toggle button](http://spacefold.com/colin/posts/2007/images/synthui/my_widgets/toggle_button_states.png): You need to press it again to release, not unlike the vote buttons here.